# how to hide results data if results been not found

Tags: angular, ionic3

i want to `hide`  `searchResults` based on found `elements` and on clicking  `x` button i want to hide whole results

the `backpress` `key`  is also not responding in my case

here is my demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1j9sbj?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

```
export class HomePage {


showSearchBar = true;  

haveSomeResults = false;

resultsData:any;

  searchResults = {
    "details": [{
        "user_id": "73",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.com",
        "token": "217808036f0215fee13aee8925574899"
    }, {
        "user_id": "74",
        "email": "hemanthraj2009@gmail.com",
        "token": "fe4fd5fa58075a69dd7e323cd0f1f2ad"
    }, {
        "user_id": "75",
        "email": "ggsgowtham17@gmail.com",
        "token": "9ed2839e54980a34e968e61d2bae362f"
    }, {
        "user_id": "76",
        "email": "contact@saddamhussain.com",
        "token": "e798b517a4171e1108e6809228c63c9c"
    }, {
        "user_id": "77",
        "email": "david123@gmail.com",
        "token": "5ddea6e5ebc38bbdb4cf48c828250f40"
    }, {
        "user_id": "78",
        "email": "sharukhkhan@gmail.com",
        "token": "d9494e94f1d1b1c5ea4eb509519a109c"
    }, {
        "user_id": "79",
        "email": "halwar@gmail.com",
        "token": "e80eb532f754cb30338bdd6b08cb11de"
    }, {
        "user_id": "81",
        "email": "hungama@gmail.com",
        "token": "ea060affe298542dd3498e3fa0ff3a9f"
    }, {
        "user_id": "82",
        "email": "haleem123@gmail.com",
        "token": "e0da36b6e3557ff64489de5c2a6d989f"
    }, {
        "user_id": "83",
        "email": "ejazanwa@gmail.com",
        "token": "117e4d5d2382ceb138c409640d1e33ac"
    }, {
        "user_id": "84",
        "email": "ejazanwar3457@gmail.com",
        "token": "0027c64433e84cbb9bf6e9a282c49c56"
    }, {
        "user_id": "85",
        "email": "ejazanwar77721@gmail.com",
        "token": "1c7cb381b8bf3f77764a54dc47dc74a5"
    }, {
        "user_id": "86",
        "email": "ejazanwar774547@gmail.com",
        "token": "e8049af25b5f866554ff3dc4abcbd74f"
    }, {
        "user_id": "87",
        "email": "ejazanwar777www@gmail.com",
        "token": "260c59d317fdf5c98f04a738653b888d"
    }, {
        "user_id": "88",
        "email": "ejazanwar77wqwq7@gmail.com",
        "token": "fe8d7166cf23ca540e275cbd154bdedb"
    }, {
        "user_id": "89",
        "email": "ejazanwar777sass@gmail.com",
        "token": "c6c263a682a600243ab502b21d1f4144"
    }, {
        "user_id": "90",
        "email": "ejazanwar77nndfnndf7@gmail.com",
        "token": "0b253d6ca088d7a409a57a249544ecd1"
    }, {
        "user_id": "91",
        "email": "ejazanwar777sasasa@gmail.com",
        "token": "9e13046ff6ab89827b8e63c389a97d5e"
    }, {
        "user_id": "92",
        "email": "ejazanwar777dxcvb@gmail.com",
        "token": "75323972b13cacd35a287e8a5b580e27"
    }, {
        "user_id": "93",
        "email": "ejazanwarewwe777@gmail.com",
        "token": "69ce1e6ffa5e34fcbb74e15e70d73cc3"
    }, {
        "user_id": "94",
        "email": "ejazanwar7dds77@gmail.com",
        "token": "f4e9a701f9dae581ecbc2abf1470f88f"
    }, {
        "user_id": "95",
        "email": "ejazanwar777rehrere@gmail.com",
        "token": "7937784df2d5d004d627795b80f39783"
    }, {
        "user_id": "96",
        "email": "ejazanwar777awddddd@gmail.com",
        "token": "73586d8c8a1ccb2305268526646dc83d"
    }, {
        "user_id": "97",
        "email": "ejazanwar77eqwew7@gmail.com",
        "token": "4ab7a92230fda8ab622ad8e3bc7e9376"
    }, {
        "user_id": "98",
        "email": "ejazanwar777dsggds@gmail.com",
        "token": "3481a3c17a752ef136a4eadeaa0813f4"
    }, {
        "user_id": "99",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.comsaasas",
        "token": "6bd7941c8b501f798c8854047a395bdf"
    }, {
        "user_id": "100",
        "email": "ejazanwar777jgfjgfjfg@gmail.com",
        "token": "127934324e39ad681826322632f91259"
    }, {
        "user_id": "101",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.comsddsbsdbsd",
        "token": "9125af9544be0515124e16f7171c36a7"
    }, {
        "user_id": "102",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.comdssdsd",
        "token": "48d0ac8443944489fb235444994ba44a"
    }, {
        "user_id": "103",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.comwwewewee",
        "token": "2585718f2b2d65610d681f8764f6baca"
    }, {
        "user_id": "104",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.comwq",
        "token": "88d84fadaafa36092a8099c5e28574d4"
    }, {
        "user_id": "105",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.combdbbdasd",
        "token": "3cdc18853781cf36ba4345fe6e431e0b"
    }, {
        "user_id": "106",
        "email": "ejazanwar777dfsghfd@gmail.com",
        "token": "39b2b79d0fa3e88c5f23bcdb56eefec4"
    }, {
        "user_id": "107",
        "email": "ejazanwar77adsfdasf7@gmail.com",
        "token": "1a6c860fc6d6a2875f4de371dee22b22"
    }, {
        "user_id": "108",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.comdddd",
        "token": "684aae9542ddc76f1f78c4360afe8846"
    }, {
        "user_id": "109",
        "email": "jhddfhfdfdhdhfjhj@gmail.com",
        "token": "069fe4f0ec2210c1e8eb9400486f1718"
    }, {
        "user_id": "110",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.comssdssdd",
        "token": "a10f3620d18466a0d5780749401052ad"
    }]
};


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }


  showSearchData($key){

     this.haveSomeResults = true;
  }
```

here is my demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1j9sbj?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-np1r5a

Comment: i will updated my answer for your question. if you click close icon in inside the searchbox the results will be hide. using searchkey i will hide and show the result in results div. *ngIf="searchkey"

Comment: Try `(keyup)="showSearchData(searchkey)"` instead of `(keypress)="showSearchData(searchkey)"`.

Answer (score 0):

In any case so far you're not filtering the data, so I assume your question is "how do I register a backspace". You could do this through ngModelChange, like so:

```
  <ion-searchbar *ngIf="showSearchBar" 
       (ngModelChange)="valuechange($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchkey"> 
  </ion-searchbar>
```

Component:

```
valuechange($key) {
    console.log($key);
    //filter your list through $key value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="showSearchBar" (ngModelChange)="showSearchData($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchkey"> 
    </ion-searchbar>
```

Check the data here:

```
showSearchData($value){
    if($value)
     this.haveSomeResults = true;
     else
      this.haveSomeResults = false;
  }
```

Working solution: https://ionic-np1r5a.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`ngModelChange`** event here, then you can check if the value is present in the parameter hence enable and disable the results.

```
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="showSearchBar" (ngModelChange)="showSearchData($event)" [ngModel]="searchkey"> 
</ion-searchbar>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://ionic-4q7enb.stackblitz.io)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

use ***ngIf="searchkey"** instead of *ngIf="haveSomeResults"

```
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="showSearchBar" (keypress)="showSearchData(searchkey)" [(ngModel)]="searchkey"></ion-searchbar>
<div *ngIf="searchkey">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let searchResult of searchResults?.details">
        <ion-avatar item-start>
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{searchResult.user_id}}</h2>
        <h3>{{searchResult.email}}</h3>
        <p>{{searchResult.token}}</p>             
    </ion-item>     
</div>
```